# Postgresql listen in database function as continuously

Tags: postgresql, triggers, postgresql-9.5

I have a postgresql notify function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.mynotify() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    PERFORM pg_notify('myEvent', row_to_json(NEW)::text);
    RETURN new;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql;
```

And I set it as a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger
  AFTER INSERT
  ON public.mytable
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.mynotify();
```

I want to listen this notifications to write another table (`events`) on this same database.

But I could not create a listener function. Is this possible? Or should I use a programming language like java or c#?

Comment: Here you can find a working daemon example in Python: [dtheodor/listen_pg.py](https://gist.github.com/dtheodor/126fc329960a714f1945)

Comment: You may be also interested in [Postgres Background Worker.](https://github.com/vibhorkum/pg_background)